# Is the pushforward of the dualizing sheaf of a stable curve locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : C\rightarrow S$ be a proper flat morphism whose geometric fibers are stable curves in the sense of Deligne-Mumford.

Let $\omega_{C/S}$ be its dualizing sheaf. Must $f_*\omega_{C/S}$ be locally free?

I'm happy to assume that $S$ is connected and locally noetherian, but I don't want to make any other assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is locally free of rank $g$ and it is called the Hodge bundle. The way to prove this is by combining duality with "cohomology and base change". The latter tells you that given a proper flat family $f:X\to S$ and an $S$-flat coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, if 
$$
b^p_s(F):R^pf_\ast F\otimes_{\mathscr O_S}k(s)\to H^p(X_s,F_s)
$$
are isomorphisms for $p=i$ and $p=i+1$ (and all $s\in S$), then $R^{i+1}f_\ast F$ is locally free.

We need to apply this to our family of stable curves $f:C\to S$ with $F=\omega=\omega_{C/S}$ and $i=-1$. Cohomology and base change certainly commute for $i=-1$, that is, the maps $b^{-1}(\omega)$ are trivially isomorphisms. The maps $b^0(\omega)$ are also isomorphisms by the duality isomorphism $R^1f_\ast \omega_{C/S}\cong \mathscr O_S$. Indeed, by cohomology and base change again, if $R^{p+1}f_\ast F$ is locally free around $s\in S$, then $b^p_s(F)$ is an isomorphism.